# how to test all my Service are injected into component

Tags: angular, jasmine

how to test all my Service are injected into component

```
class TestComponent {
    constructor(testService: TestService) {}
}
```

in case if anybody remove the service from component constructor my test case should fail.

Comment: you probably shouldn't test if services are injected you should rather test if they are used correctly (for example some methods on those dependencies are called in some situations). Can you explain why would you want to test if all dependencies are injected maybe then there will be some better answer to your problem?

Comment: What reason would you have for doing this? I'd have expected that if somebody removed the dependency, your tests would fail to compile - making such a test irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

We can make `TestBed` as a  dummy Angular Module and we can configure it like one including with a set of providers,

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [TestService]
});
```

Then  resolve a token into a dependency using it’s internal injector and `TestBed`,

```
testBedService = TestBed.get(TestService);
```

Then your test case be like,

```
it('Service injected via inject(...) and TestBed.get(...) should be the same instance',
    inject([TestService], (injectService: TestService) => {
      expect(injectService).toBe(testBedService);
    })
);
```

Refer https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/dependency-injection/